# Подсчёт, сколько раз в базе данных повторяется выбор региона

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте!

Как сформировать подобный запрос?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В базе есть регионы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сформировать SQL запрос который бы высчитывал сколько работ в том или ином регионе (Т.Е сколько повторяющихся регионов находится в базе данных)

На сей момент имеем такое:

```
<tr>
    <td><p class="array">Наименование субъекта Российской Федерации</p></td>
    <td><p class="array">Количество работ</p></td>
</tr>

<?php
    include 'bd.php';

    $resul = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `register_user` ORDER BY `region`");
    $ar = mysql_fetch_array($resul);
    do
    {
    echo ""."<tr><td><p class='array'>".$ar[region]."</p></td><td><p class='array'>".$ar[uchname]."</p></td></tr>"."";
    }
    while ($ar = mysql_fetch_array($resul));
?>

</table>
```

Comment: select count(region) from <название таблицы> where region = 'название региона' group by region

Comment: @Youlfey это получается для всех регионов так нужно делать?

Comment: Если нужны все сразу можно просто количество строк подсчитать.

Comment: Ну, мне нужно вывести конкретно в таком виде: https://imgur.com/a/WqE98

т.е если совпадений нет, прочерк напротив региона, в ином случае считает его

Comment: select region, count(region) from <название таблицы> group by region

Comment: Попробуйте так.

Comment: @Youlfey Спасибо, то что нужно!